# Pythons Curses Library and Resizing

Tags: python, ncurses, curses

I have been working on a terminal GUI using python and [Curses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html#module-curses)  for the past few days and feel I am not making any progress. Right now what I need to do is create two panels that both take up half the screen minus 1 - 2 characters as a margin. I want these windows to be able to handle resizing so if the user decides to make their screen larger or smaller my panels resize to adjust to the user's needs.

```
+---------------------------+ +---------------------------+
|                           | |                           |
|                           | |                           |
|                           | |                           |
|                           | |                           |
|                           | |                           |
|                           | |                           |
|                           | |                           |
|                           | |                           |
|                           | |                           |
|                           | |                           |
+---------------------------+ +---------------------------+
```

At This time I can draw the windows and have them resize. The issue is that if I resize smaller then what my boxes are currently set I get an error.

```
_curses_panel.error: move_panel() returned ERR
```

I am not sure if this is due to how I am checking and resizing the window or a limitation of Curses.

Can you please take a look at my code and let me know if I am losing my mind or not?

```
import curses
import curses.panel
screen  = curses.initscr()
curses.start_color()
curses.noecho()
curses.curs_set(1)
screen.keypad(1)
curses.cbreak()
height,width = screen.getmaxyx()

window = curses.newwin(1,1,1,1)
window2 = curses.newwin(height -2 ,(width/2)-10, 1,width/2+1)

left_panel = curses.panel.new_panel(window)
right_panel = curses.panel.new_panel(window2)

window.border('|', '|', '-', '-', '+', '+', '+', '+')
window2.border('|', '|', '-', '-', '+', '+', '+', '+')

curses.panel.update_panels()
curses.doupdate()

running = True
x = 0
while ( running  ):
    height,width = screen.getmaxyx()
    k = window.getch()
    if k == curses.KEY_RESIZE:
        window2.erase()
        window.erase()
        h, w = screen.getmaxyx()
        window2.resize(height - 2 ,(width/2)-10)
        window.resize(height - 2,(width/2) - 10)
        left_panel.replace(window)
        right_panel.replace(window2)
        left_panel.move(0,0)
        right_panel.move(0,width/2)
        window2.border('|', '|', '-', '-', '+', '+', '+', '+')
        window.border('|', '|', '-', '-', '+', '+', '+', '+')
    if k == ord('q') or x >= 10:
        running = False
        curses.endwin()
    curses.panel.update_panels()
    curses.doupdate()
```

This code is after I did a lot of trial and error so there may be some code that just does not make sense but all the logic for handling resizing is in this if statement.

```
if k == curses.KEY_RESIZE:
```

Comment: I suspect the problem is that you are calling `screen.getmaxyx()` before the call to `.getch()` that returns the resize event, and therefore you are using the old screen dimensions rather than the new ones.

Comment: I love you I would mark your comment as a resolution but I don't think I can do that to comments.

Answer (score 0):

You code `h, w = screen.getmaxyx()` but you not use h,w variable after that.
the height,width variable you use is get before `getch()`.

So you should remove the `height,width = screen.getmaxyx()` and change the `h, w` to `height, width`.

And advise to use curses.wrapper(). to make Terminal back to its normal state when crash occur.

Use `width//2` to support Python3.

```
import curses
import curses.panel

def main(screen):
    height,width = screen.getmaxyx()

    window = curses.newwin(1,1,1,1)
    window2 = curses.newwin(height -2 ,(width//2)-10, 1,width//2+1)

    left_panel = curses.panel.new_panel(window)
    right_panel = curses.panel.new_panel(window2)

    window.border('|', '|', '-', '-', '+', '+', '+', '+')
    window2.border('|', '|', '-', '-', '+', '+', '+', '+')

    curses.panel.update_panels()
    curses.doupdate()

    running = True
    x = 0
    while ( running  ):
        # height,width = screen.getmaxyx()
        k = window.getch()
        if k == curses.KEY_RESIZE:
            window2.erase()
            window.erase()
            # h, w = screen.getmaxyx()
            height,width = screen.getmaxyx()
            window2.resize(height - 2 ,(width//2)-10)
            window.resize(height - 2,(width//2) - 10)
            left_panel.replace(window)
            right_panel.replace(window2)
            left_panel.move(0,0)
            right_panel.move(0,width//2)
            window2.border('|', '|', '-', '-', '+', '+', '+', '+')
            window.border('|', '|', '-', '-', '+', '+', '+', '+')
        if k == ord('q') or x >= 10:
            running = False
            curses.endwin()
        curses.panel.update_panels()
        curses.doupdate()

curses.wrapper(main)
```